# Join tables based on name fields with different formats using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have two separate databases with tables containing information that I need to join together based upon a person's name.

Table1 has multiple columns

```
FirstName1, FirstName2, LastName1, LastName2
```

`FirstName1` & `FirstName2` may or may not have a middle initial "Name I"
`LastName1` & `LastName`2 may or may not have multiple last names

Table2 has one column `FullName`

FullName is generally formatted - first [middle (sometimes just an initial)] last
There may be multiple first/last names

Table1 is about 500k records long, Table2 is about 5000.

- I need to write something which returns all of the records from
  Table2 that have a likely corresponding name in Table1.
- Not all records from Table2 will be in Table1.
- Since multiple people having the same name is possible, it is
  expected that a record from Table2 could likely match multiple
  records from Table1.
- The names from Table2 need to be checked against both
  FirstName1+LastName1 as well as FirstName2+LastName2

It doesn't have to be a perfect result, just the most likely matches.

Comment: Writing a convoluted query for this would probably not be a good idea. All the substring and concatenation in the where clause will degrade performance. It would be better to write a stored procedure that uses a temp table, loop over the 5000 records in table1 and select from table2 in a way that uses the index. Store results in the temp table and select from it in the end.

Comment: This is just a dump of your requirements, there is no question, no evidence of own efforts.

Comment: @user2773289 if the OP is looking for approximate matches, then no query will be able to use indexes. Levenshtein distance or similar fuzzy matching need to be applied.

Comment: An SQL JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them. There is no common field between them. Because of that, try with query inside query.

Comment: If must be relation between tables for build query upon them, what here is not, I see solution only in PHP loop through every columns in table1 and name from every row find in table2 column FullName.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't started yet because my idea seems highly inefficient..  
My idea was to break the names from Table2 into individual parts and compare them to LastName1 & LastName2.  If there was a match, I would compare the other parts of the Table2 array against the corresponding FirstName1/2.

I would then store the # of matching terms from Table2 and rank the results based on the number of matches.

This is going to take forever to run though, so I was hoping for a more elegant approach.

Comment: Is this a one off reconcilliation or will you be attempting this regularly? Can you change the table structure? What *are* the table structures (if the description you've given is all there is to tell then I recommend you give up now).